# Moving A HorizontalView Smoothly with Video Frames in it

Tags: java, android, video, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am having an issue with moving a Horizontal Scroll View containing Video Frames, with the help of timer. The problem is that the scrolling is not smooth as you can see in the video(Link below). The code that I am using to move the Horizontal ScrollView is given below:

```
**`float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final float px = (int) 4 * density;
    //4 is in PX here(Pixel)

    Log.v("DPPX__", "ORIG PX: " + px);
    Log.v("DPPX__", "Converted PX: " + (int) px);
    Log.v("DPPX__", "DP: " + 4);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    checkingTimer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy((int) px, 0);
            setCurrentVideoTime();
        }

    },0,200);//Update text every 200 milliseconds`**
```

As you may have guessed from the code, that I am moving the scrollView by 4 pixels every 200 Milliseconds. So in order to make it smoother, i tried to move it by 1 pixel every 50 milliseconds, but the problem that arises by doing this is that the ScrollView only accepts the scrolling parameter in INTEGERS. But in order to move the scrollView in DPs, i had to convert the pixel to DP, to rotate, so the value that comes is in Float. But the ScrollView accepts only Integer parameter in ScrollViewBy or smoothScrollby methods.

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Video Link: https://youtu.be/GFvsUF6upHI

[Image of the Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivFq8.png)

Comment: **200** millisecs is not smooth, try **33**, also try setting `...smoothScrollBy(3, 0)`.

Comment: @VC.One in order to reduce 200 to 33, we will also have to reduce 4 to respective value. 3 wouldn't work. In order to reduce the time to 33, we will have to move the scrollView by 0.66. But that's the main problem. We cannot give float/double value to the scrollBy in ScrollView. It only accepts Integer.

Comment: @VC.One, if we do the roundOff for this 0.66 value, it will disrupt the Scrolling behavior. And it won't match the videoview length etc